# Range of values in Haskell list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I'm giving a shot at functional programming, right now using Haskell and practicing list comprehensions. I'm trying to define a function to generate a list of squares...

So far, I have this function:

```
squares = map (^2) [2..]
```

What I want to do now is to generate squares only between a range low -> high. I'm generally trying to figure out how to specify a range of values in a Haskell list comprehension. Could someone lend a hand?

Answer (score 2):

You can work with `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` to check items and take/drop as long as the predicate is satisfied, so:

```
squares = (dropWhile (< low) . takeWhile (<= high) . map (^2)) [2..]
```

For example for `low = 5` and `high = 123`, we get:

```
Prelude> (dropWhile (< 5) . takeWhile (<= 123) . map (^2)) [2..]
[9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121]
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do now is to generate squares only between a range low -> high […] in a Haskell list comprehension

I presume you mean that you want to select the *squares* that are in this range, rather than the *inputs* in a particular range, but I’ll go over both. Also, you’re not using a list *comprehension* currently, just a list, but I’ll also show how to use both.

First of all, your original code can be expressed with `map` and a list, or with a list comprehension.

```
squares = map (^ 2) [2 ..]

squares = [x ^ 2 | x <- [2 ..]]
```

There is no difference in result between the two; the first just avoids naming the intermediate variable `x` using an *operator section* `(^ 2)` = `\ x -> x ^ 2`.

In a list comprehension, you can include *guards*, which are Boolean expressions that filter the resulting list at that point. The function equivalent is `filter`.

```
squaresBetween (low, high)
  = filter (\ s -> s >= low && s <= high)
    $ map (^ 2) [2 ..]

squaresBetween (low, high)
  = [x ^ 2 | x <- [2 ..], x ^ 2 >= low && x ^ 2 <= high]
```

Instead of repeating the `x ^ 2` expression, you can bind it to a variable in a comprehension using `let`:

```
squaresBetween (low, high) =
  [ s
  | x <- [2 ..]
  , let s = x ^ 2
  , s >= low && s <= high
  ]
```

And instead of the Boolean expression, you can use the function `inRange` from `Data.Ix` (in `base`), which is equivalent:

```
import Data.Ix (inRange)

squaresBetween (low, high)
  = filter (inRange (low, high))
    $ map (^ 2) [2 ..]

squaresBetween (low, high) =
  [ s
  | x <- [2 ..]
  , let s = x ^ 2
  , inRange (low, high) s
  ]
```

This approach with guards or `filter` is suitable when the input is a finite list. However, because the input list here is an infinite *stream* of numbers (`[2 ..]` = `enumFrom 2`), both of these functions will *also* produce infinite streams. The language has no way of knowing, in general, that the comprehension will filter out all of the values > `high`, so it will continue producing and discarding elements, and never reach the end. E.g. in GHCi, evaluating this will hang before printing the end of the list `]`.

```
> squaresBetween (0, 100)
[4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100
```

You can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit this computation, which will appear as `^C`. GHCi will print `Interrupted.` and return to the prompt.

One solution to this is to use functions such as `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` to filter out elements instead of a guard / `filter`. `takeWhile` *selects* the longest prefix of a list matching a condition, and `dropWhile` *deletes* a prefix.

```
squaresBetween (low, high)
  = takeWhile (<= high)     -- 3. Keep those not over ‘high’.
    $ dropWhile (< low)     -- 2. Discard those under ‘low’.
    $ map (^ 2) [2 ..]      -- 1. Generate a stream of squares.
```

This can be broken down into smaller parts and composed together:

```
between (low, high) = takeWhile (<= high) . dropWhile (< low)

squaresBetween range = between range $ map (^ 2) [2 ..]
```

You can of course combine the two styles, in whichever form you find easiest to understand.

```
squaresBetween range = between range [x ^ 2 | x <- [2 ..]]
```

If you wanted to select the *numbers* whose squares are in the given range, then a good approach is to *pair* each value with its square, then use `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` with conditions on those pairs:

```
squaresBetween (low, high)

  -- 3. Select only the numbers, not their squares.
  = map fst

    -- 2. Keep and discard pairs by their second element.
    $ takeWhile (\ (_x, s) -> s <= high)  
    $ dropWhile (\ (_x, s) -> s < low)

    -- 1. Generate (number, square) pairs.
    $ [(x, x ^ 2) | x <- [2 ..]]
```

`squaresBetween (0, 100)` would then generate `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. And these lambdas can be written as compositions instead: `(<= high) . snd`, i.e. “the second element is ≤ `high`”.

Another solution is to use a finite input range at the beginning, since you know that no value greater than the square root of `high` will exceed `high`. Then a filter or guard is suitable:

```
squaresBetween (low, high) =
  [ s
  | x <- [2 .. limit]
  , let s = x ^ 2
  , s >= low && s <= high
  ]
  where
    limit = round (sqrt (fromIntegral high)) + 1
```

And it produces a finite result.

```
> squaresBetween (0, 100)
[4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]
```

`fromIntegral` converts from an integer to a fractional number, `sqrt` takes the square root, and `round` converts it back to the nearest integer (using “banker’s rounding” / “round to even”).